# need ideas for blockchain dapp that gives information on wait times

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I want to make a blockchain dapp that lets one monitor a que (say a line up to an event or wait time in line for passports etc) or book someone to do the waiting. A gig economy sort of app-except you book ppl to wait in lines, etc. Perhaps these folks doing the gigs can give hourly updates on line conditions.

I want some element of being able to book people and that essentially auto assigned, muh like uber does when one books a driver.

I'm using flutter/dart for my front end of this dapp.

Can anyone hook a girl up with links to similar contracts??

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

while it's not your specific use case, here's an example of a 'gig economy' use case involving smart contracts, where a tesla owner and a customer agree on a contract to rent out the tesla to the customer for the short term https://github.com/pappas999/Link-My-Ride